# Replace wildcard value with variable using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using php and need to find the wildcard string defined below. I then need to append a string onto the end of the wildcard value.

The value is "awn.Funnel.Widget.createForm("awn.co.uk", "--wildcard--here--")

Here's what I've tried:

```
if (preg_match('/awn.Funnel.Widget.createForm("awn.co.uk",[_a-zA-Z]+/', $competition_code, $matches)) { print_r ($matches); }
```

But it gives me:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 52
```

Comment: Provide concrete examples pls.

Comment: So do it! What have you tried, what does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex:

```
'/awn.Funnel.Widget.createForm("awn.co.uk",[_a-zA-Z]+/'
```

should be rewritten as:

```
'/awn\.Funnel\.Widget\.createForm\("awn\.co\.uk",[_a-zA-Z]+/'
```

OR better use **[preg_quote function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)**:

```
$regex = '/' . preg_quote('awn.Funnel.Widget.createForm("awn.co.uk', '/') 
         . '[_a-zA-Z]+/';
```

Answer (score 1):

That first argument to preg_match:

```
'/awn.Funnel.Widget.createForm("awn.co.uk",[_a-zA-Z]+/'
```

is a regex pattern.  As such, the character '`(`' is interpreted as the start of a capturing group.  Since this is not what you want here, you need to escape the paren:

```
'/awn.Funnel.Widget.createForm\("awn.co.uk",[_a-zA-Z]+/'
```

You should also escape '`.`', since those will be interpreted as any character if not escaped, rather than as a period.